# Video and audio playback not working on iOS

Tags: ios, media-player, codenameone

I'm trying to incorporate video and audio file attachment to forum posts in an app, and the playback isn't working on iOS. On Android it works fine. The code looks like this (for audio, and similar for video):

```
String localAudiofilePath = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + (String) fileInfo.get("path");
InputStream is = null;
Media m = null;
try{
    is = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(localAudiofilePath);
    m = MediaManager.createMedia(is, "audio/" + extractFileExtension((String) fileInfo.get("path")));
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

m.play();

final Media mm = m;

Display.getInstance().scheduleBackgroundTask(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      while(mm.isPlaying()){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {         
        }
      }
      mm.cleanup();
    }
});
```

I don't see any errors in the console, and when debugging I see the `catch` block is not entered. However, no sound comes out of the device when I try to play the audio, and the video player remains blank, giving me this message in the console:

> 2018-01-18 04:22:20.213822 MyApplication[24425:2262915] [Playback] ❗️Playback failed with error: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x61000024c2d0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12893 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12893), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}, not resolving (canResolve: YES, errorResolver: (null))

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not at all media playback.  The file wasn't actually present on the device, even though no exception was reported by iOS nor was the `catch` clause ever entered.  My incorrect assumptions were 1. that I could use try/catch around the input stream instantiation as a means of checking if the file exists (it worked on Android but not iOS), and 2. that the operating system would necessarily throw an exception if the file wasn't present (not the same as 1., but tied into it).

My new, working code looks like this:

```
String localAudiofilePath = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + MyApplication.DIRECTORY_APP_DOWNLOADS + "/" + (String) fileInfo.get("path");
if(!FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(localAudiofilePath)){
    Cn1FileUtils.downloadRemoteFile("https://medonline.co.il/uploads/" + (String) fileInfo.get("path"), (String) fileInfo.get("path"), true);
}
InputStream is = null;
media = null;
try{
    is = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(localAudiofilePath);
    media = MediaManager.createMedia(is, "audio/" + Cn1FileUtils.extractFileExtension((String) fileInfo.get("path")));
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();        
 ToastBar.showErrorMessage(MyApplication.getInstance().getString("error_loading_file"));
    return;
}
media.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the audio recording mime type to playback a video. I guess Android ignores it which is fine. The iOS port sees an audio format for the stream data and assumes this is an audio file. You need to specify the mime file type of the video you are playing.

Comment: This is audio playback

Comment: Is this the same audio type as the one returned by this method? Notice that iOS and Android return different types as their native support for audio recording is a bit different

Comment: I updated my code, since it had a few issues.  Now the mime type matches the original file, but I still get no sound out of the iphone, and no errors in the console.  I even tried it with recordings made with the very same iPhone, and still nothing.

Comment: Check that the device isn't muted, notice that some apps play sound while a device is muted on iOS. It's possible that the cleanup code is happening before the audio starts as `isPlaying` might return false initially as playback is asynchronous.

Comment: I tried not calling `cleanup()`, and unmuting the device as well. Still no change. The file plays clearly on my computer